# PHP SQL Session and user's id / user agent / ip etc

Tags: php, sql, session, session-variables

I would like to grant my users access to open sessions on their accounts..

So i'm going to use PHP-SQL Session but the functions that I found on Internet (open/write/gc/read etc..) have static parameters so I cannot add my own..

How to give to this methods more parameters like user ID, remote IP etc.. for logging into DB ?

I followed this tutorial : http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Managment-System-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i understand it wrong but what you can do is:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "username");
$pass = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password");
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT id FROM tbl_users WHERE username=?
AND password=?")) {
  $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
  $stmt -> execute();
  $stmt -> bind_result($userid);
  $stmt -> fetch();

  $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
$stmt -> close();
```

Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Hey, the "data" field in my DB contain "PVPN_UID|s:1:"2";" where "PVPN_UID" is what i've done with "$_SESSION['PVPN_UID'] = 2;" How to parse this data ?